# How come my mac pro failed to wake up?

Tags: mac, sleep-wake

I have been trying to wake up my mac pro from sleep daily using System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Schedule. The laptop is connected to a power adapter, but still my laptop failed to wake up.

Anyone know why this happen, and if there is other way to do this?

Thanks,
Sharon

Comment: forgot to add, the currently on High Sierra version 10.13.6

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Just so you know, you can edit your question to add further details as you need. (There's an 'edit' link below it). Also, your title and question refers to a 'mac pro' but your question also states, *The laptop is connected to a power adapter, but still my laptop failed to wake up*. Can we assume your'e talking about a MacBook Pro and not a Mac Pro?

Comment: First  we would ask if you set up the times correctly, do you have 12h or 24 hour clock. Is you system clock accurate ?

Comment: yes, it's macbook pro, and I am pretty sure the system clock is accurate.